# Execute an external function in a loop while the main program continues normally

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm developing a telegram bot in python.
I'm using python-telegram-bot and my objetive is make an option that allows me to make the bot consult the price of X currency every X seconds/minutes/hours and return it to me in a message, at the same time the bot must be able to execute other types of queries.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def func1():
    while True:
        print("I'm in the func1!")
        time.sleep(3)
        func2()

def func2():
    print('Also in the func2!')
    return 'Hi!'

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p2.start()
```

So this is an example of my actual code. Here works perfectly but when I put it in practice only works the process 1 (process who's invoke the function that consult price) and process 2 (process that continue in the main code) it's completely ignored

```
def remember_process_starter(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    p1 = Process(target=remember(update, context))
    p2 = Process(target=main_menu(update, context))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    

def remember(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    Alert.alert(update.message.text)
```

That is the part of the real code who invokes both functions.
Remember is the function that invoke the consultant funcion (in other python file)
main_menu returns the user to the main menu of the bot.

Comment: Are you familiar with asynchronous programming and multithreading? I believe that if you run this function on a separate thread you wouldn't get any problems.

Comment: I tried to do it in another thread and it is exactly the same problem, while true is the problem. In tkinter I would fix this with the after() method. I need to find an alternative to that devilish while true